# UIScrollView does not resize correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios4

I have code to rotate and size a scrollview, such that when the iPhone is landscape the orientation is correct.

This is what the view looks like before rotating:
[image]

The scroll view is in yellow.

This is what it looks like after:  [image]

This is the log statement i put after setting the new frame for the scroll view, and you can see that it is clearly not what it says its supposed to be!

```
CGRect for object after setting to new: UIScrollView, {{0, 100}, {480, 150}}


    [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration animations:^{
        CGRect boundsRect = anObject.frame;
        boundsRect.origin.x = x;
        boundsRect.origin.y = y;
        boundsRect.size.width = width;
        boundsRect.size.height = height;
        anObject.frame = boundsRect;
        NSLog(@"CGRect for object after setting to new: %@, %@",[anObject class], NSStringFromCGRect(anObject.frame));
    } completion:^ (BOOL finished){
        if (finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration animations:^{
                anObject.alpha = 1.0;
            }];
        }
    }];
```

What am i missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the parent view of the UIScrollView isn't re-laying it out when you rotate?  Perhaps you need to do the final resize in `- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation` so the frame doesn't get resized out of your control.